# PythonでのTypeError(TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding')が出てしまいます

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda3

**・実行したい内容**
jupyternotebook上でtresuredata上からデータを取得したいのですが、TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'が出てしまって困っています。
特にencodingを明示的に指定しているわけでもないのにエラーになってしまっています。

**・記述したコード**

```
#必要ライブラリをimport
    import os
    import sys
    import gc
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import scipy.stats as st
    from scipy.stats import norm
    from scipy import stats
    from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler  
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import seaborn as sns
    import math
    import datarobot as dr
    import pandas_td as td
    import logging
    import argparse
    import msgpack_numpy
 #tresuredataからデータを取得。apikeyとendpointを設定
    con = td.connect(apikey="{...}", endpoint='...')
 #tresuredataにapikeyを渡す
    con = td.connect(apikey=os.environ['TD_API'], endpoint='...')
 #実行
    con
 #dbとtype(presto or hive)の設定
    engine = con.query_engine(database='...', type='presto')
 #SQLを読み込み
    sql = 
    '''
    select *
    from db.table
    where time = ...
    ;
    '''
#読み込んだSQLを実行
    df= td.read_td_query(sql,engine)
```

**・試したこと**
mspackのアップデート
参考サイト
https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/2810#issuecomment-425414118

以下のコードを実行

```
def to_bytes(getters, exclude):
    serialized = OrderedDict()
    for key, getter in getters.items():
        if key not in exclude:
            serialized[key] = getter()
#    return msgpack.dumps(serialized, use_bin_type=True, encoding='utf8')
    return msgpack.dumps(serialized, use_bin_type=True)
```

参考サイト
https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/2868

**・補足情報**
pythonのバージョンは3.8.5です。
anaconda3の環境で実施しており、直前に再インストールしております。
再インストールの前には発生していなかったエラーです。
※同じコードでエラーなく読み込みができました。

何卒よろしくお願い致します。

**・追記**

ご指摘を頂いたのでエラーメッセージを追記致します
ご指摘頂きありがとうございます。

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-f4d0c907ab18> in <module>
      1 #読み込んだSQLを実行
----> 2 df= td.read_td_query(sql,engine)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_td\td.py in read_td_query(query, engine, index_col, parse_dates, distributed_join, params)
    528     # execute
    529     r = engine.execute(header + query, **params)
--> 530     return r.to_dataframe(index_col=index_col, parse_dates=parse_dates)
    531 
    532 def read_td_job(job_id, engine, index_col=None, parse_dates=None):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_td\td.py in to_dataframe(self, index_col, parse_dates)
    283     def to_dataframe(self, index_col=None, parse_dates=None):
    284         columns = [c[0] for c in self.description]
--> 285         frame = pd.DataFrame(iter(self), columns=columns)
    286         if parse_dates is not None:
    287             frame = self._parse_dates(frame, parse_dates)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    561         elif isinstance(data, abc.Iterable) and not isinstance(data, (str, bytes)):
    562             if not isinstance(data, (abc.Sequence, ExtensionArray)):
--> 563                 data = list(data)
    564             if len(data) > 0:
    565                 if is_dataclass(data[0]):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_td\td.py in __iter__(self)
    267 
    268     def __iter__(self):
--> 269         for record in msgpack.Unpacker(self, encoding='utf-8'):
    270             yield record
    271 
msgpack/_unpacker.pyx in msgpack._cmsgpack.Unpacker.__init__()
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'
```

Comment: エラーメッセージは略さないで全て記述してください。呼び出しのスタックトレースとか何のモジュールで発生したか等の重要な情報が抜け落ちてしまいます。

Comment: ご指摘頂きありがとうございます。
コメント欄では文字数オーバーしてしまったため、本文（質問）へエラーメッセージの追記させて頂きました。

Comment: 逆に`msgpack_numpy`の版数が新しすぎるとかありませんか？ 参考サイトではその下に Seeing the exact same issue as @yuyuhan0306. Researched this a bit more and found [#2810 (comment)](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/2810#issuecomment-425414118) which solves it. で `Current workaround: pip install "msgpack-numpy<0.4.4.0"`のようですし。また [treasure-data/pandas-td](https://github.com/treasure-data/pandas-td)は **deprecated** で今は[treasure-data/pytd](https://github.com/treasure-data/pytd) になっているようですので、使用している各モジュール/パッケージ間の版数やAPIの機能変更等の整合性が取れているかを確認(どうすれば良いかは分かりませんが)した方が良さそうです。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！
バージョンが新し過ぎるといけないなどがあるのですね、知りませんでした。。。原文読み直し＆バージョンを古いものに置き換えるなど対応してみようと思います。
また、エラーが出た後、anacondaをアンインストール→再インストールをしたのですが、その際に元のアンインストールがうまくできていないなどで依存関係がおかしくなってしまったのかもしれません。こちらも調査してみます。

Comment: 調査：msgpack-numpyのバージョン
現状のバージョンが0.4.3.2であり、新しすぎるということはなさそうでした。
念の為「pip install "msgpack-numpy<0.4.4.0"」実行しましたが、「Requirement already satisfied」のため新しすぎるということはなさそうでした。

Comment: 読み込みエラーが解決しました。
やった内容
anaconda環境をクリーンにし、Python単体で環境を再構築
必要最低限のライブラリをインストール
※結果的にどこがどう悪さをしていたかはわかりませんでしたが、環境を入れ直し、必要最低限のライブラリにしたところ、うまくいきました。
コメント頂いた方、またご覧いただいた方ありがとうございました！